# Taking coordinates of Test.pos file type not possible!

Tags: coordinates, zref

**1. Test.tex**

Running Test.tex (see below) saves the coordinates (as pt, not mm or sp) of

> \eins{title 1}{some text }

in the file Test.pos, which is:

[image]

```
% this is Test.tex

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=210 mm,paperheight=297 mm,textheight=0mm,left=30mm,right=0mm,top=40mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
    \topskip=0pt 
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
    \usepackage{zref-abspos} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Producing .pos file %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=\jobname.pos\relax 
\newcommand{\eins}[2]%
{\zsavepos{#1}
    {#2}% Output the text provided as mandatory argumentm
    \immediate\write\mywrite{\withoutpt{\the\dimexpr \zposx{#1}sp \relax},\withoutpt{\the\dimexpr \zposy{#1}sp \relax}}% 
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% makes the output in .pos without pt %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\withoutpt[1]{%
    \strip@pt\dimexpr \dimexpr#1\relax\relax
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}


\eins{title 1}{some text }


\end{document}
```

**2. Testtt.tex**

Testtt.tex takes the pdf "blabla.pdf" and puts "some new text..." to the coordinates (10,20) (in pt)

```
% this is Testtt.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210 mm,paperheight=297 mm,textheight=0mm,left=30mm,right=0mm,top=40mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\topskip=0pt 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 


\begin{document} 
    \includepdf[
    picturecommand*={
        \put(10,20){some new text for the coordinates in Test.pos}%
    }]{blabla.pdf}
\end{document}
```

However if I change

> \put(10,20)

to

> \put(\input{Test.pos})

It doesnt work. So it doesnt take the coordinates in Test.pos.

Doe someone have an idea? Thanks for helping!

Comment: the two aguments of `\put` have to be separated by a literal comma and _expand_ to the required lengths. Your `\input` has no literal comma and it makes many internal assignments before finally typesetting the two values. Depending what your real use case is you can probably get your first file to write `\put(85.35,731.24)` to a text file and then `\input` that file into the second document.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesnt work that way.
File ended while scanning use of \put . }]{blabla.pdf}
appears

Comment: that's fixable I may answer later if no one else does

Comment: if I \input the text file with \put(85.35,731.24){some new text}, then it works! Interesting, why combining doesnt work... But now i think i know how to handle. 
The interesting thing here is, even I change .pos to .text or .tex or to something else, it works. So it seems that .XXX doesnt change. Thats weird

Comment: No that's expected as the end of file is at a safe place not between the arguments, it is same if you end a file with `\mbox{hello}` that is OK but if you end it with `\mbox` and have `{hello}` in the top level file that will error

Comment: now I cant compile Test.tex such that the Test.pos will produce \put(85.35,731.24){some new text}. It only can produce put(85.35,731.24)some new text (without the \ and the braces). It cannot handle it...

Comment: write `\string\put`

Comment: It worked! Wow, interesting. Thanks a lot :) Let see if i can combine all things together

Comment: hopefully my last question:
if in the "some new text" part appears german letter like ä,ü,ö etc. it cannot handle it. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: that's because you are using low level write not the latex commands but you can use `\detokenize{german letter like ä,ü,ö}` to write the literal utf8 text